# How to work with percentage rates instead of px rates in responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend

So I've applied for a front end job few months ago and got interviewed and they've given me a test task. One of the requirements of this task is that they want the website to be infinitely variable scalable [like this one](https://we3.jam3.com/developer). 
To quote the task description it says:

**If you scale down the browser window, everything fits perfectly because everything scales in the same ratio. For that you have to work with percentage rates instead of px rates.**

Now, my problem is I am a **PX** guy, I mean I build all of my projects using **px** and not that confident on using different unit such as `em, vw, rem` etc. Well I've use other unit like `vh` but I don't use it often.

So what's the best way to learn or any roadmap that'll help me to migrate from px to percentage. Should I just use tools like [px to em](http://pxtoem.com/)?

Comment: Try using `vw` and `vh` everywhere, sometimes you will see that it won't look as good on mobile devices. If this is the case you can use media querys to fix this. To learn you should try to change one of the sites you allready made all the way to `vh` and `vw` units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Practice does make perfect

The short answer is... Start practicing using percentage-based units as that's how you'll learn the little catches. This is a good career move anyway as the idea of matching pixels to a design was crushed long ago with HiDPI screens, mobile devices, etc all rendering pixels differently.

### Getting Started

Practically, you need a place to start and that means learning a few new CSS tools.

#### First

Use `rem` as a substitute for pixels. 
Unlike an `em` that's relative to its parent font-size, a Rem is relative to the **font-size** of the root element (usually `body`) which means its GLOBAL. You can use rems everwhere (font-size, margin, padding, position, etc) and they're ALL based on the root size.

So let's say the root font size is 16px (typical browser default). That means `1rem = 16px`. Now a 16px base isn't overly useful when you're doing math in your head. Jonathan Snook wrote about [why this works](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) years ago but the basic formula is set the base font size to 62.5% (of 16px) this means that `1rem = 10px` and it's much easier to do the math.

Here's what that looks like in code:

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 2.4rem;
 /* 2.4rem = 24px */
}

p {
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 /* 1.2rem = 12px */
}

.padding-left {
 padding-left: 2rem;
 /* 2rem = 20px */
}
```

You get the idea...

*Fun tip: once you like the layout you can change the body font-size and make everything bigger or smaller. This is useful for things like a small screen where you want the fonts to be a bit larger*

#### Next

`CSS Calc()` Is your friend. It's designed to help you do math operations on mixed unit values. For example, the browser can then do this type of math: 33.33% - 200px.

```
.element {
   width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
   /* maybe you need responsive columns with 10 px of padding on either side */
}
```

#### Finally

Start doing all your layout in percents. For example instead of a 3 column layout set to 300px wide (not responsive). You should make them `100/3 or 33.3333333%` wide. Percents like this are always based on the parent so `100% = parent's width` (regardless of the parent's units).

As a side note, I rarely need to use `vh/vw`, not because they aren't useful but in general, elements overflow their window in very predictable ways and percents are easier to wrap your head around.

Answer (score 1):

vw and vh are going to be your best bet if it needs to be a percentage of the screen.  rem and em are still relative to a starting point (i.e. body { font-size: 16px; } and scaled from there.  vw and vh do have some issues on smaller device screens though, but it looks like your demo website has this issue.  You can fix this with media queries, but it doesn't look like your example did, it "infinitely" scales as you mentioned.